# Does the sum of two functions satisfying the intermediate value property also have this property?

Tags: calculus, analysis, continuity

If functions $f$ and $g$ both satisfy the intermediate value property, does their sum also satisfy this property? If not, what if I suppose in addition that $f$ is continuous?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I found the second part of my question here: 
[Is the sum of a Darboux function and a continuous function Darboux?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2659170/513723)

Comment: The best thing you can aim for is to show that the image of $f+g$ is an interval. (In particular it takes all the values in-between but not necessarily in the right order)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider the functions, $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [-1,1]$ and $g:[0,1]\rightarrow[-1,1]$ where

$$f = \begin{cases}\sin\frac{1}{x},& x>0 \\ 0, & x = 0\end{cases}$$
and
$$g = \begin{cases}-\sin\frac{1}{x},& x>0 \\ 1, & x = 0\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What if we suppose that one of the functions is continuous? Or should I ask this in another question?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it is true or not in that case. Sorry

Comment: I just found the same question, see my edit!

Comment: Interesting, makes sense that I couldn’t think of a counterexample