# the property of intermediate values

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

**Question**

Show that if $f\colon\mathbb R\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ is a derivable function then $g(x)=f(x)+f'(x)$ has the property of intermediate values.

And if we consider $h(x)=f(x)+f'(x)+f''(x)$ ?

**Attempt**

Since $f$ is differentiable then it is continuous, if $f'$ is continuous then $f+f'$ is continuous and by the intermediate value theorem $g$ has the property. But what if $f'$ is not continuous ? Does Darboux's theorem guarantee that $f'$ has the property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous, it has a primitive $F$. $F + f$ is derivable and its derivative is $f + f'$. Since it is a derivative, it has the IVT property.

Same for $f + f' + f''$ with $F + f + f'$.

Comment: Can you get a resolution without primitives?

Comment: @PedroCosta That's a good question. We could try proving that a Darboux function + a continuous function is a Darboux function. Which would be more general than using a primitive, since some Darboux functions are not a derivative. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give a try too. Good job.

Comment: @PedroCosta Actually it is false; cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2659170/is-the-sum-of-a-darboux-function-and-a-continuous-function-darboux

Comment: I think in let $h(x)=e^xg(x)$ in $I\subset \mathbb R$. $h(x)=j'(x)$, where $j(x)=e^xf(x)$. $h$ have a property. As $g(x)=e^{-x} h(x)$, $g$ have a IVT.  But $g(x)=f(x)+f'(x)$

Comment: But in this answer exist a little problem. Is who proof that if $f$ has the IVT then so does $f^{-1}$. That's true?

Comment: $f^{-1}$ has the IVT property is equivalent to: $f$ domain is an interval. But how do you prove that $g$ has IVT? The product of a Darboux function by a continuous function is not necessarily Darboux.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I had also noticed that detail (great detail). It seems to me impossible not to even use the notion of primitive or something similar.

Comment: By the way, the fact that $f^{-1}$ has the property IVT proves that if $f$ is not defined in an interval then can we guarantee that $f^{-1}$ is not continuous ?

Comment: Yes, if $f$ is defined on a domain that is not an interval, then $f^{-1} is not continuous.

Comment: Right, Thanks you.