# Is $f'-f$ darboux?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

Suppose $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and (not necessarily continuously) differentiable on $(0,1)$. Darboux's theorem tells us that the intermediate value theorem holds for $f'$. Does the intermediate value theorem hold for $f'-f$?

More generally, does $f$ continuous, $g$ darboux imply $f+g$ darboux?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2659170/42969 for the second question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first part apply Darboux's theorem on $$h(x) = f(x) - \int_{0}^x f(t)\mathrm dt$$

Comment: A similar argument works for $ff'$ as $ff'={1\over 2}(f^2)'.$